# How do I prevent selecting text in AngularJS on ng-dblclick?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an element with `ng-dblclick='doSomthing()'` which works fine, but has the ugly side effect of selecting the text in the element too. It there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried to move your text into a `Button` ?

Comment: Maybe `e.preventDefault();`?  I'm not that familiar with AngularJS, so I wouldn't know, but give a try - maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 16):

Try to add these css rules to your class or div that you want to prevent the text selection of

```
.myClass {
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: This is not supported in IE 8 or 9.

Comment: this is a terrible thing to do to a website. I think a better option would be to explicitly block selection only where a user should be double clicking but not to select

Comment: @pcnate I couldn't agree more! This is why in my example I am applying these rules to a specific css class called "myClass" and not any top level elements (div, span, button, etc). You can simply apply "myClass" or whatever you'd like the class name to be to any elements that you want to block the text selection of.